# React Conditional Rendering inside .map empty screen

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do conditional renderin inside with this function:

```
renderNewBuildingModel = () =>{
if(this.state.newBuildingModel){
  return(

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.newBuildingModel} toggle={this.openNewBuildingModel} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.openNewBuildingModel}>New Building</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
          <ListGroup>
            {
          this.state.buildings.map((b) => {
            <ListGroupItem>
            <div className="newBuilding">
            <img className="newBuildingImage"src={b.img}/>
    <span className="newBuildingName">{b.name}</span>
            </div>
            <Label className="newBuildingDesc">{b.description}</Label>
            <div>
            {b.wood != undefined ? <Label className="newBuildingDesc">Wood Cost:{b.wood}</Label>: null}
            {b.stone != undefined ? <Label className="newBuildingDesc">Stone Cost:{b.stone}</Label>: null}
            </div>


            </ListGroupItem>

          })
        }
      </ListGroup>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.openNewBuildingModel}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>

  )
}

}
```

I just get empty model screen.This happened after adding b.stone ! = ... and b.wood != ... conditional lines.

[image]

edit:

I solved my problem by going back in time and rewriting code :)

Comment: Try wrapping your Label in parenthesis. I wonder if the colon after Wood Cost: and  Stone Cost: are messing with your ternary which is also expecting a colon between the truthy and the falsy result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just remove "console.log(b)" to make it works.